# C# SCOM, access a sharepoint site mailbox

Tags: sharepoint-online, exchange

Is this possible?

I know I can use EWS to access mailboxes but can it be used on site mailboxes? If so how?

the other weirdness to this is, we log into sharepoint or exchange using service accounts that have different domains (@XYZ.com) and the site mailboxes have @ABC.com

this is using sharepoint online 2013 and exchange 2013

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see SPO site mailboxes through Exchange panel or by writing get-mailbox. They are visible as users in Azure. The naming is also by design (you should have Prefix-Site@domain.onmicrosoft.com, with "SMO-" being the default prefix). You can change it with Powershell or Site Mailbox Provisioning Policy:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28559.creating-sharepoint-online-site-mailbox.aspx

You can tap into properties of a mailbox by using CSOM:

```
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteurl)   
$ctx.Credentials= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password) 
$rootWeb = $NULL 
$rootWeb = $ctx.Web 
$ctx.Load($rootWeb) 
$ctx.ExecuteQuery() 
$webProps = $NULL 
$webProps = $rootWeb.AllProperties 
$ctx.Load($webProps) 
$ctx.ExecuteQuery() 
Write-Host "Mailbox found:" $webProps["ExchangeTeamMailboxEmailAddress"] 
Write-Host $webProps["ExchangeTeamMailboxSiteCollectionUrl"] 
Write-Host $webProps["ExchangeTeamMailboxSiteID"] 
Write-Host $webProps["ExchangeTeamMailboxSharePointUrl"]
```

Comment: does using the CSOM allow you to read the emails in the box and get attachemtns etc from them?

We have some site boxes that work with EWS and others that don't.